# Android:Inbox Unread count Gmail public labels api

Tags: android, count, gmail

Im using following 
api to fetch user inbox details. Ive downloaded the sample app and it works fine but now i want to fetch the int count of unread All Mail items which for me seems to be impossible as the cursor loader isn't replying to what i need..kindly help

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html this is the api im using

Comment: I solved it by iterating through the cursor with the following piece of code  while(data.moveToNext())
            {
             if(data.getString(3).equals("All mail"))
             {
              Log.i(TAG, "Received cursor with4 #: " + data.getInt(5) + "::"+ data.getColumnName(5));
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data.getInt(5)+"", 1000).show();}
              i++;
            }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect incoming email notification in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499588/detect-incoming-email-notification-in-android)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40960192/1136074